# Fire iblazr programmatically

Tags: android, ios, photography, iblazr

How do you fire the [iblazr](http://www.iblazr.com/) programmatically?

No API I can find, they're not responding to inquiry.

I'm looking for a solution for iPhone and Android.

Comment: I think you'll be better of asking the people at iblazr...

Comment: Did a few days ago via email, haven't received any response, figured I'd check here.

Comment: Write in support@iblazr.com or i.chuba@iblazr.com

Comment: Any solution? I'm also writting them right now.

Comment: @pozuelog, nope they never got back to me. :( If you find out how, please post here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They finally published it here:
https://github.com/ConcepterDev/iblazr-original-protocol

You can control the original iblazr by sending the specified tone for the specified duration to the headphone jack:

```
function         frequency (Hz)  duration
----------------------------------------------
wake iblazr      800             200±150ms
flash            15750           300ms (auto)
pre-flash        10000           until focused
constant light   2500-9500       infinite
```

Comment: I can see android sdk here: https://github.com/ConcepterDev/iblazr-sdk-android. But I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to enable the flash device with the media volume at max, I suspected it must have something to do with the volume output that triggers it.
So, I plugged it in, started my music player, and it started flashing to the music for the most part.
Turning down the volume stopped the flashing and turning it back up caused the LED to again start flashing.

Based on that I would assume you simply have to output a loud audio clip to turn it on while the media volume is set to max.

**Update:**

After experimenting on my theory, the device I have (iblazr compatible 16 LED Chinese version), the frequency of the tone is the key and determines the brightness.  Using the Windows API Beep(frequency, duration) function, the light first turns on at a frequency of 6500 and gets brighter as the frequency increases.  Seems like it is pretty bright at 7000!

Comment: Hey, I never ended up buying a iBlazr so I have no way of testing but I'm just gonna trust you as 1) that sounds like some good research! and 2) no one else has bothered to answer. Thanks for checking it out and I think I might buy one now!